# How can I get a legend to appear on my plot using my own desired colours?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I have a plot in which I would like to include a legend.

I have tried some solutions that were proffered to others, but the issue in my case was that I couldn't use my desired colours as the solutions required me placing `colour` within `aes()`, which produced different colours to the ones I specified.

I'm sure that the solution lies within `scale_fill_manual`, but I can't implement it correctly.

As such, how can I include a legend and keep the same line colours?

My data frame:

```
grouped <- structure(list(date = c("2018-07-16", "2018-07-17", "2018-07-18", 
"2018-07-19", "2018-07-20", "2018-07-21", "2018-07-22", "2018-07-23", 
"2018-07-24", "2018-07-25", "2018-07-26", "2018-07-27", "2018-07-28", 
"2018-07-29", "2018-07-30", "2018-07-31"), homepage_opens = c(5L, 
0L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
    sitewide_opens = c(39L, 34L, 19L, 62L, 46L, 44L, 16L, 51L, 
    25L, 66L, 75L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), chats_started = c(10L, 
    16L, 9L, 8L, 13L, 13L, 5L, 13L, 4L, 8L, 11L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L), chats_completed = c(7L, 13L, 8L, 4L, 5L, 9L, 6L, 
    13L, 2L, 7L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -16L))
```

My plot code:

```
ggplot(grouped) +
  geom_line(aes(x = date, y = sitewide_opens, group = 1),
            linetype = "dashed",
            colour = "forestgreen",
            alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_line(aes(x = date, y = homepage_opens, group = 1),
            colour = "blue") +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = 8),
             linetype = 2,
             colour = "black") +
  geom_text(aes(x = date, y = homepage_opens, label = homepage_opens),
            hjust = -0.15,
            vjust = -1.5,
            size = 3,colour = "black") +
  geom_text(aes(x = date, y = sitewide_opens, label = sitewide_opens),
            hjust = -0.15,
            vjust = -1.5,
            size = 3,
            colour = "black") +
  labs(title = "Title",
       x = "Date",
       y = "Count") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 25,
                                  face = "bold",
                                  colour = "black"),
        legend.position = "top",
        panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text = element_text(colour = "black"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost right, you need to adjsut scale, but colour not fill (as you use colour to set color of line and fill to set what color is filling your object. Here is solution.

```
ggplot(grouped) +
  geom_line(aes(x = date, y = sitewide_opens, colour = "Sitewide opens",group = 1),
            linetype = "dashed",

            alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_line(aes(x = date, y = homepage_opens, group = 1,
                colour = "Homepage opens")) +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = 8),
             linetype = 2) +
  geom_text(aes(x = date, y = homepage_opens, label = homepage_opens),
            hjust = -0.15,
            vjust = -1.5,
            size = 3) +
  geom_text(aes(x = date, y = sitewide_opens, label = sitewide_opens),
            hjust = -0.15,
            vjust = -1.5,
            size = 3,colour = "black") +
  theme(legend.position = "top",
        legend.title=element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text = element_text(colour = "black")) + 
  scale_colour_manual(values=c("Sitewide opens"="forestgreen", "Homepage opens"="blue"),                                                 labels=c("Sitewide opens", "Homepage opens"))
```

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't reshaping the data be a bit more robust?

Comment: @AlienDeg Thank you, this works well but how can I remove the word `colour` from the legend and change the legend text from `sitewide_opens` to `Sitewide Opens`?

Comment: theme(legend.title=element_blank())

Comment: @MusTheDataGuy adjusted code.

Comment: @AlienDeg Thank you, this is good but the legend text isn't quite right as it contains an underscore; is it possible to change the text to read `Sitewide opens` and `Homepage opens` with no underscores?

Comment: Just change the aes color name to whatever you want then copy to the scale color name.

Comment: @MusTheDataGuy new code, new pic :)

Comment: @AlienDeg Yes, this works perfectly. The labels were the wrong way around so I fixed that, but otherwise it's great. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you use `ggplot2`, you should feed it *long* data. This makes it much easier to add more lines, text, or whatever (as @MusTheDataGuy already mentioned). Therefore, here a minimal `ggplot2`-style example (further, transform date to what it is...date - `ggplot2` knows what to do with it and you don't need `group`):

```
grouped_long <- tidyr::gather(data = grouped, key = key, value = value, -date)

ggplot(data = subset(grouped_long, key %in% c("homepage_opens", "sitewide_opens")),
       aes(x = as.Date(date), 
           y = value, 
           label = value,
           color = key, 
           lty = key)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_text(color = "black") +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 8, lty = 2) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c(sitewide_opens = 2,
                                   homepage_opens = 1)) + 
  scale_color_manual(values = c(sitewide_opens = "forestgreen",
                                homepage_opens = "blue"))
```